# How to check if a user exists on LDAP

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, active-directory, ldap

I need to verify users in the company using only their username - not their password.

So I need a method like this

```
public bool UserExists(string username)
{ ... }
```

I am aware of the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace but don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

There are 80,000+ records so try to bear that in mind.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I have done it - my code is:

```
private bool UserExists(string userName, string domain)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry.Exists("WinNT://" + domain + ".[hidden].com/" + userName);
        return true;
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is correct, but it seems to work so far.

Michael's answer has two relevant parts:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#22
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#35

**Update #2:**

I actually used this:

```
public static bool LoggedOnUserExists()
{
    var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

    UserPrincipal foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Environment.UserName);

    return foundUser != null;
}
```

Comment: You should **NOT** use the WinNT provider anymore - it's strictly for backwards compatibility, but it typically doesn't work well in a AD network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 and up, you can use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespaces to do this quite simply:

```
public bool UserExists(string username)
{
   // create your domain context
   using (PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
   {
       // find the user
       UserPrincipal foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, IdentityType.Name, username);

       return foundUser != null;
    }
}
```

This will work with the regular user name `John Doe`, or alternatively you can use the user's e-mail address (`john.doe@company.com`), or his distinguished name (`CN=John Doe`) - see what the `IdentityType` enumeration has to offer :-)

Comment: I assume this searches on the current domain? Is there anyway to use this method and specify a domain?

Comment: @Eddie: sure - the [`PrincipalContext` has numerous overloaded constructors (perfectly documented on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx), which allow you to specify a domain and/or a container in that domain to use for searching