# SSO using Windows Login in C#

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have a Linux-served Web app and a C# Windows client.  The web app currently allows AD credentials, which it authenticates.

Not all the users are Windows-based.  I'm trying to implement a Single Sign-on solution for Windows users.  I want to allow access to my application if the user has already been validated against AD at Windows log-in.

I know how to validate credentials against AD:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain,
                userName, password);
```

But I won't have the userName or password.  I know that Kerberos is being used by AD to store the Windows credentials but I don't know how to access the ticket.

My question is similar to ['How to determine if logged on windows account has been authenticated on domain'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663439/how-to-determine-if-logged-on-windows-account-has-been-authenticated-on-domain) or ['Authenticating users using Active Directory in Client-Server Application'](http://Authenticating%20users%20using%20Active%20Directory%20in%20Client-Server%20Application) except for C#.

I am using LightTpd.

Comment: All users that log on to an AD-connected windows box are already authenticated (otherwise they couldn't log on).  Do you mean that you are trying to authorize users based on AD permissions?  See authorization vs authentication http://www.duke.edu/~rob/kerberos/authvauth.html

Comment: I want to access the authentication ticket.

Comment: Why?  Enabling windows (AD) authentication in IIS is fairly trivial and ***extremely*** thoroughly documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: My web app isn't hosted by IIS.  It is a linux server.

Comment: If your web app is hosted on linux, then how is it running C#?  Or are you trying to run some C# on the windows box to somehow pre-authenticate the user against the web application?

Comment: Your question needs to be about how to enable integrated kerberos auth between <your webserver> and <your client>.

Comment: @Chris Shain, The web app isn't running C#, I have a Windows app in C# that connects to the web app.

Comment: @BrianCauthon, that is the logical next step of my problem.  I thought to use local Windows login ticket and somehow pass that to the web app.  You are saying that is the wrong initial approach?

Comment: We can't tell what your initial approach is, because you haven't posted any code to show us what you are trying or pseudo code to demonstrate what you want to try. However, I get the feeling that what you want to try wont work or will make kerberos insecure.

Comment: Of particular use would be the code that you use to connect to the web application.  For instance, are you using the WebClient class?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Providing Active Directory authentication via Kerberos protocol in Apache](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555092). If you're using the WebClient or WebRequest classes in the Windows app make sure that you set the `UseDefaultCredentials` property to true.

NOTE: Microsoft killed the original but the content can still be found in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110225440/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555092).

Comment: If you're using something other than Apache you'll need to specify what.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @TravisRivera Seems like Microsoft killed the article. The Wayback Machine still has a copy.